# How to solve a recurrence relation over a polynomial sequence?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, recurrence-relations

We have a sequence of polynomials - polynomials indexed by natural numbers: $Z$, with initial conditions: $$Z_0 = 1, Z_1 = 1$$ and the recurrence relation being: $$Z_n = Z_{n-1} - p(1-p)Z_{n-2}$$where p is the dummy variable in each polynomial.

Hence, upon solving the recurrence relation one at a time, we get:
$$Z_2 = p^2 -p+1$$$$Z_3 = 2p^2-2p+1$$$$Z_4 = p^4-2p^3+4p^2-3p+1$$$$Z_5 = 3p^4 -6p^3 +7p^2 -4p +1$$

How to solve for $Z_n$?

Comment: See [auxiliary polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) for one solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$Z_n=C_1\lambda_1^n+C_2\lambda_2^n,$$
where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are roots of the following equation
$$\lambda^2-\lambda+p(1-p)=0.$$
Thus, $\lambda_1=p$, $\lambda_2=1-p$ and solve the system:
$$C_1+C_2=1,$$
$$C_1p+C_2(1-p)=1.$$
I got $$Z_n=\frac{1}{1-2p}\left((1-p)^{n+1}-p^{n+1}\right).$$